# C# Array: How do i fill an array with results which get from functions in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I try to fill the an array with the result which get from below function.

The function is:

```
   private int Sum(int i)
   {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                s += j;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

I create an array and then try to use SetValue() or evaluate directly to fill the array with the results.

for example, `Array[1]=Sum(1);`

However, none of them works.

=====================================================

[Update for more details]

I need use an array with large amount.

```
int[] arr = new int[10000]
```

I try use below codes

```
    foreach (int i in arr)
    {

        arr.SetValue(Sum(i),i);
    }
```

And

```
    for(int i = 0; i<10001; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=Sum(i);
    }
```

None of them works.

======================================================

Is there a way to fill the array with functions?

Sorry for my poor English. :(

Thanks

SuT

Comment: Could you show us the code that declares and creates the array?

Comment: Chances are, the problem is in how you declared the array. You can't add members to the array dynamically; you need a different storage class for that.

Comment: After you added the code, I see only two small problems (using the “for” array, not “foreach”, that is completely wrong): 1. If you create an array with new int[10000], the items are indexed 0 to 9999, not 10000, i.e. you need to do i<10000, not i<10001 (or, better, just do i<arr.Length). 2. You do not declare and initialize s in your Sum() function. Otherwise, the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is meant to use lists, dictionaries and others instead of raw arrays (see FoxCop error messages for your code for details). So i think your task should be solved as follows:

```
    class Program
    {
        static int moo(int a)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < a; i++)
                if (a % i == 0)
                    return i;

            return a;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                a.Add(moo(i));

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("a[{0}] = {1}", i, a[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** do not forget to initialize your array/list/whatever (e.g. call its constructor).

Comment: I've tried this, but always get error, which says 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'...

Comment: That means you are trying to execute non-static (object-dependent one) method from within static one. E.g. if your method/function **does not depends** on class fields you **should** make it static.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you showed works just fine. You just have to make sure that the array actually exists, and that it's large enough. Avoid the name `Array` as there is a class with that name already.

Example:

```
int[] myIntegers = new int[2]; // creates an array with indexes 0 and 1
myIntegers[1] = Sum(1); // calls the function and puts the result in the second item
```

You can use a loop to set all the items in an array:

```
int[] myIntegers = new int[42];
for (int i = 0; i < myIntegers.Length; i++) {
  myIntegers[i] = Sum(i);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but always get error, which says 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'...

Answer (score 0):

well you can create a variable int sum = 0; call the function sum and store the result of function in the variable and use that variable to populate the array as and when you need..for ex:array[1] = sum;

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have the array declaration wrong. The brackets indicating that you're declaring an array need to follow the *type*, rather than the variable name. It should look like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[10000];
```

The second problem is that you're confusing the brackets used for array indexing and method arguments. Square brackets `[ ]` are used for array indexing, and curved parentheses `( )` are used to surround the arguments passed to a method. So your code should look like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Sum(i);
}
```

And third is that `Length` is a *property*, not a method. That means you don't put parentheses after its invocation. (See the code above.)

You may find the following MSDN article helpful as you're trying to work with arrays: [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your correction. And I've tried perform the program with correct format, it did not works...

Comment: @SuT: What exactly didn't work? I see you've commented to some of the other answers that you got "An object reference is required..." error. That means you're declaring/creating the array in one place (like at the top of your code file?) but then trying to access/fill it from inside of a `static` method (like `Main`). A `static` method is one that is not associated with any particular *instance* of a class, so it can't access variables that are associated with instances. The simple fix is to declare your array object as `static`, too: `static int[] arr = new int[10000];`

Comment: It's my mistake...My codes have some other errors. And it works now.
Thanks again. :)